# "If" function not recognizing value of variable after being imported from text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently learning Python and I'm creating a Python 3 Text RPG which has saving capabilities. The text is saved in a text file, and it's then imported back into variables when you close the script and re-open it.

The problem I'm having is that my "If" calls are not recognizing that chrClassNum is actually a certain number, when it actually is. For example, if chrClassNum was 1, the "If" call would not recognize that it is a 1, and would skip past it.

I've tried modifying the script to include str() prefixes before chrClassNum.
I've also tried modifying the script to remove the speech marks, but to no avail.

```
def loadSave():
    clear()
    # Opening save file in read-only for transfer to the script
    # Reading all the lines individually as each line is different data
    f = open("save.txt","r")
    lines = f.readlines()
    chrName = (lines[1 - 1])
    chrClassNum = (lines[2 - 1])
    print (chrClassNum)
    # Currently broken, does not recognize that chrClassNum is equal to any number
    if (chrClassNum) == ("0"):
        chrClass = ("Berserker")
    elif (chrClassNum) == ("1"):
        chrClass = ("Warrior")
    elif (chrClassNum) == ("2"):
        chrClass = ("Tank")
    # Bug check, incase the user manages to break the program
    else:
     print("Somehow you got here. The script broke.")
     time.sleep(100)
     exit()
```

I expected the output to be the same which is printed in;

```
print (chrClassNum)
```

However, the output is that it just drops straight down to the "else" call, which they should not be able to access.

Comment: Why do `chrName = (lines[1 - 1])` instead of `lines[0]`?

Comment: Why all the parentheses?

Comment: Are you checking for the correct values? are they strings or integer values?

Comment: @Guy I was testing it with 'str' prefixes, I forgot to remove all the parentheses where I used str(chrClassNum).

Comment: https://pastebin.com/raw/yjsKGX7V Improved version of the script. This may or may not fix it, depending on what the actual error is

Comment: The values returned by `.readlines()` *includes the terminating newline character* (except possibly for the very last line).  So the second line isn't going to be `"0"` or whatever, it's going to be `"0\n"` instead.  You could call `.strip()` or `.rstrip()` on the line to get rid of the newline before doing the comparisons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have some whitespace in the string, remove it with `strip()`. And anyway it'd be better to use numeric comparisons, try this:

```
chrClassNum = int(lines[1].strip())
print(chrClassNum)
if chrClassNum == 0:
    chrClass = "Berserker"
# etc.
```

I also deleted unnecessary brackets, and simplified index calculation.